# ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree. .net core 3.1 with vue js

Tags: vue.js, npm, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to build my application but getting following error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
  npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! While resolving: clientapp@0.1.0
  npm ERR! Found: vue@2.6.14
  npm ERR! node_modules/vue
  npm ERR!   vue@"^2.6.12" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
  npm ERR! peer vue@">=3.0.0" from vue-chartkick@1.1.0
  npm ERR! node_modules/vue-chartkick
  npm ERR!   vue-chartkick@"^1.0.0" from the root project
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
  npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
  npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Anyidea waht i am missing

error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1.
Content of my csproj file from where i create build is

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="VueCliMiddleware" Version="3.1.2" />
</ItemGroup>
<PropertyGroup>
    <SpaRoot>clientapp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<!--<ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
</ItemGroup>-->
<Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <!-- Build Target:  Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Exec Command="npm --version" ContinueOnError="true">
        <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js and npm are required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
</Target>

<Target Name="EnsureNodeModulesInstalled" BeforeTargets="Build" Inputs="package.json" Outputs="packages-lock.json" Condition="!Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules')">
    <!-- Build Target: Restore NPM packages using npm -->
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- Build Target: Run webpack dist build -->
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Running npm build..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build --modern" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**" />
        <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
            <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
            <ExcludeFromSingleFile>True</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
        </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked is deleting
%appdata%\Roaming\npm-cache folder the node_modules folder locally

Comment: It would be helpful to understand WHY this worked and whether or not there are unintended negative consequences

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems that you have Vue 2 installed, but the package`vue-chartckick` is looking For Vue 3.

Also, the package readme states:

> The latest version works with Vue 3. For Vue 2, use version 0.6.1 and
> this readme https://github.com/ankane/vue-chartkick/blob/v0.6.1/README.md.

So, the solution is either use the recommended version of the package or upgrade Vue to version 3.

Comment: I can't upgrade to vuejs 3 as whole application is quite a bit tested on it. how can i edit my .csproj file stuff to target specific version as command call there is npm install which install all the required pacakge

Comment: I'm not a .net developer, but you should have a `package.json` file in your project root, find the specific requirement `vue-chartkick` and edit it to target the specific version: `"vue-chartkick": "0.6.1"`. then build again (better after removing `node_modules` directory)

Comment: I have uploaded my package.json at https://files.fm/u/b7pt24ctk like you are not a .net developer. i am not a vue js dev :)

Comment: yep. in line 27 you have `"vue-chartkick": "^1.0.0",`. replace it with: `"vue-chartkick": "0.6.1",`. note the missing `^`.

Comment: After that correction i am now getting axios18.0/20.0 related errors

Comment: I've tried installing packages from your `package.json`. I got no errors. when and what error exactly do you get?

Comment: unable to resolve dependency tree
  npm ERR! While resolving: clientapp@0.1.0
  npm ERR! Found: axios@0.20.0
  npm ERR! node_modules/axios
  npm ERR!   axios@"^0.20.0" from the root project
  npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
  npm ERR! peer axios@"^0.18.0" from vue-trend-chart@0.15.3
  npm ERR! node_modules/vue-trend-chart
  npm ERR!   vue-trend-chart@"^0.15.3" from the root project
  npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
  npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
  npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resoluti

Comment: delete `node_modules` directory and `package.lock` file, and try again. the previous errors presumably broke the dependency tree. after a failed `npm install` is always better to start clean

Comment: node_modules folder not created, there is no pacakge.lock file also not there yet